# python -m venv <envname> fails on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-venv

I tried to run:

```
python -m venv my_venv_name
```

It fails with this message:

```
Error: Command '['\\\\ (redacted path) \\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I have a fresh install of Python 3.6.5 including pip 9.0.3. `python -m pip` works. The install is user-local and the only Python installation. This is in a corporate environment where pip can't access external stuff (surely it doesn't need to?) It's all in my user area: both the full python install and the venv target directory are on a network drive.

(I've redacted part of the path to Python in the error message)

How can I fix this? Should I report it as a bug? The error message would be confusing for a beginner following the basic tutorial.

**Conclusion: Don't work on UNC paths. Map a drive letter.**

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
python -m venv --without-pip my_venv_name
```

The [options are documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)

Comment: While that works, it's only a partial solution as I'd prefer to use pip to install whl files. Also I'd like to know what's wrong! This is after all pretty much copy/paste from the basic tutorial, it shouldn't be bleeding edge. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to know what's wrong, please post the output of `python -m ensurepip -vvv`

Comment: I failed to get a perfect replication of all parts of the problem so I won't post the -vvv output: it showed pip WAS installed in the venv, but I can't reproduce that starting from scratch: I don't want to post output which could waste time. I did reproduce the original problem. Enough for now and thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the solution. It can't cope with UNC paths. If I install on an area with a drive letter, it works.

Comment: Interesting, I don't understand why `--without-pip` was working then...

Comment: By the way did you double-up all the `\\` in the UNC path?

Comment: I didn't enter any full paths, so no. The UNC paths are in the diagnostics.